# How to check my API logs inside my kubernetes cluster in GCP

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to **check the logs of my API** but I cannot find them in **Google Cloud Platform**.

I explored **Stackdriver** but I only found the logs that kubernetes throws. I want to go deeper and check the logs that my API throws inside each pod.

Do I need to use another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write logs to the pod logs in several ways. Have a look at [Kubernetes logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) , choose whichever you like most, and implement it into your API.
Then you will find your logs via:  kubectl logs

Answer (score 2):

You can see the `kube-apiserver.log` in your Master node.

`/var/log/kube-apiserver.log - API Server, responsible for serving the API`

More references: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs

Comment: Is it enabled by default ?